# powershell Count files in folder and create text file with result in filename

Tags: powershell, file, count

If I have 10 *.csv files in a folder, I would like to create an out-file as D:\10.txt
I cannot get the syntax right, here's my last attempt:

`(Get-ChildItem 'D:\Data\' -File -Include *.csv).Count | Out-File -filepath "D:\test$($_).txt"`

I prefer a oneliner due to another system that must call this.

Can somebody help me please ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**The automatic `$_` variable - representing the current input object in each step of a pipeline - can only be used in arguments that are *script blocks* (`{ ... }`), not in *expandable strings* (`"..."`).**

A per-input-object script block is most typically used with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, but you can also use it as a [delay-bind script-block parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) with *pipeline-binding* parameters.

While that doesn't work with `Out-File`, it does with `Set-Content`, which is generally the right tool to use with *strings* anyway:

```
(Get-ChildItem D:\Data -File -Filter *.csv).Count |
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { "D:\test$_.txt" }
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `-Include` with `-Filter`, which is not only more efficient, but also avoids the pitfall of 
`-Include` only applying to the *input directory path*, not to the items *inside it* - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).</sup>

**Caveat**: In *Windows PowerShell* - but fortunately no longer in PowerShell *Core*, where (BOM-less) UTF-8 is now consistently used -  `Out-File` and `Set-Content` use different character encodings by default: UTF-16LE ("Unicode") vs. the system's active ANSI code page ("Default"); use the 
`-Encoding` parameter to specify the desired encoding, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I try with this

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\Data\*.csv'
$CountFile = $files.Count
touch "D:\$($CountFile).txt
```

I tried with a powershell emulator from Ubuntu, I hope this can help you. Greeting from Argentina

Comment: For me on Windows it doesn't work: The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet